# printing numbers greater than the given condition

Tags: c

in the program, I had given the condition to print the values of 'a' less than five. but it has printed including five. what may be the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 0
int main()
{   
    while(a < 5)
    {   
       a++;
       printf("%i\n",a);
    } 
}
```

the result of this program is
2
3
4
5

Comment: Think about the order you do things. I really recommend you learn how to use a debugger to step through your program while monitoring variables and their values. That will help you understand what's happening better.

Comment: What happened to `1` (or even `0`)?

Comment: You increment `a` before printing it... (Using post-increment makes no difference as that's a separate statement, and you should just use pre-increment in this case anyway)

Comment: Oh and the claimed output doesn't match the code, which should print `1 2 3 4 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with that code is the order in which operations are being done. Consider the last loop iteration: `a` is 4 at the beginning of the loop, so the `a < 5` check is successful and the loop is entered. Then `a++` increments `a` to 5 — but the loop is already being executed. (The loop condition is only checked exactly when it is encountered.) Then the following line prints 5, and control goes back to the top, exiting the loop because `a < 5` is now false.

In general, you'd want to increment *after* printing here:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  int a = 1; // starting from 1, not 0, since we're going to increment after
  while (a < 5) {
    printf("%d\n", a);
    a ++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, that loop is exactly what `for` loops were designed for:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  for (int a = 1; a < 5; a ++)
    printf("%d\n", a); // no braces = only one statement inside the loop
  return 0;
}
```